# Authentication on role management with Resteasy on JBoss7.1

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss7.x, resteasy

I do like to experiment on JBoss from a long time. 
Now I am facing some problem during authentication on role management with Resteasy on JBoss7.1.

Let me explain the problem.
Just i started a simple Web Application on Jboss7 with implementation of Resteasy. I am able to login by authenticating the user-role. The Problem comes when i am trying to logout. I found during Login if you do securityContext.getUserPrinicials.getName() , The username is the output as that is authenticated. But there is no session is managed for that user. so what would be the best way to implement the Logout functionality. I am pretty new to Jboss7 and Resteasy both.. Apology if i have said anything wrong..
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new to Resteasy .Servlet 3.0 module has something to do this.
I got some idea from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html).

As you have not given your sample code i have tested this following code for logout that is working fine..

```
    //import things

@Path("/userrealam")
public class UserService {
    @Context HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context HttpServletResponse response;


        @GET
        @Path("logout")
        @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
        public void logout() throws JAXBException, IOException {
            try {
                        if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null){
                        request.logout();
                      }
                      }
             catch (Exception e) {
                    }

          }
}
```

Comment: Yeah applicable with servlet3.0.